# Errors when statically linking libsndfile with vcpkg and running sf_open

Tags: c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, lib, libsndfile

So here's a bit of example code:

> #include<sndfile.h>
>
> int main() {
> SNDFILE* sndfile;     SF_INFO sfinfo;     sndfile =
> sf_open("", SFM_READ, &sfinfo);   std::cout << "Hello, World!";
> }

So basically I'm statically linking it from vcpkg, and I followed all the steps like using :x64-windows-static at the end, changing the visual studio settings and configuration file, and more, but for some reason I get these errors specifically when I compile statically and when using sf_open.

Errors:

> 3 unresolved externals
> unresolved external symbol __imp_PathCombineW referenced in function INT123_compat_catpath
> unresolved external symbol __imp_PathIsRelativeW referenced in function wpath_need_elongation
> unresolved external symbol __imp_PathIsUNCW referenced in function wlongpath

Note: Yes I do realize that libsndfile is licensed under LGPL, so I plan to include the object files since that apparently allows me to statically link it.

Comment: These look like functions from the windows api. Just google them and the msdn help page will tell you which windows library you need to link. For example PathCombineW has this help page: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) in the Reauirements section it tells you that you need to link to `Shlwapi.lib`

Comment: Even better, use media foundation directly.

Comment: Sadly I can't use media foundation directly since I want this to be cross platform. Thanks for the recommendation though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are functions from the windows api. Just Google them and the msdn help page will tell you which windows library you need to link.

For example PathCombineW has this help page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew in the [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew#requirements) section it tells you that you need to link to `Shlwapi.lib`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thank you! It worked perfectly!